# One Layout Two Projects in Android Studio

Tags: android, image, android-studio

I have a particular project that requires me to build multiple very similar apps; they're so similar that code will almost always be shared and even the layout files will be shared most of the time. However, said project is also maintenance-heavy and will feature multiple updates and changes, so I want to minimize my workload as much as possible.

Is there a way to create two projects that share everything but the 'drawable's folders? Keep in mind that it's desirable to stay in Android Studio, as that's the IDE of choice here.

For those who have any Objective-C experience, what I'm asking for is precisely the "targets" system present in xCode.

If such a thing isn't possible, is there any way to get close to it? And if it is not, are there any good alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new gradle support with Android Studio, you can use different flavors to include different classes/resources files in the same project while creating the build. SO each build will be different as per its flavor but generated using single code project.

What you can do, write the flavors in such a way so that each of your flavor will have the common classes and then also have some specific classes to that particular build.

Check this for more about flavors : http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I needed!